# PB12.5: sending keystrokes to IE OLEObject using keybd_event function/subroutine

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, sendkeys, keystroke, keystrokes

In the program I am writing, I created an OLEObject to connect to a webpage in Internet Explorer that results in an automatic pop-up prompting me for my credentials.

I've been trying to avoid having to switch tabs and manually click OK by instead sending the "ENTER" keystroke to the window using Sybase's keybd_event subroutine : http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=47760

I declared the subroutine as an External Global Function and added the code where it was needed. The interesting thing is is that the program successfully presses the OK button in the pop-up window when I step through each line in debugger mode, but it fails to do so when I compile and run it.

Could anyone give any suggestions as to how to fix this? Or perhaps propose an alternative method entirely?

Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if you are using the built in Inet, InternetResult, InternetData objects in PB, but if you are I think you use the PostURL to do something like that. Then use the GetUrl to read a webpage into the Inet object. It's been a long time since I've used this, apologize if this leads you down the wrong path.